# SQL ServerでCreate Assemblyが失敗する

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Serverはローカルネットワーク上のNAS(Synology-linux)にあり、Dockerで動いています。
Windows10マシンのSSMSからCreate Assemblyを実行すると以下のエラーを吐きます。

CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not read from the physical file 'SDS216/docker/mssql/SQLCLR/Test.dll': 50(The request is not supported.).

このエラーは、例えば存在しないファイル名、フォルダー名を指定しても吐きます。
selectやcreate databaseなどのコマンドは問題なく動作します。
何かパスの指定方法が間違っているのではないかと思うのですが、分かる方おられますでしょうか。

以下実行コマンド

```
ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
CREATE ASSEMBLY Test
from 'SDS216\docker\mssql\SQLCLR\Test.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

解決しました。パスの指定が間違っていました。

× from 'SDS216\docker\mssql\SQLCLR\Test.dll'
○ from '\mssql\SQLCLR\Test.dll'